# ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Вот файловая структура проекта:

```
\testimport\__init__.py
\testimport\f1\f1.py
\testimport\f1\__init__.py
\testimport\f2\f2.py
```

В файле **f1.py** ф-ция:

```
def foo():
    print("I'm foo() in f1")
```

Все файлы `__init__.py` пустые.
Хочу вызвать из **f2.py** ф-цию `foo()`

Вот код:

```
from ..f1 import *
foo()
```

Выводит ошибку

> ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Можно ли не меняя параметр `sys.path`, а используя только "точки" импортировать?
Какой самый легкий способ импорта?
Сколько всего способов импорта есть? у кого какие плюсы и минусы?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `\testimport\f2\__init__.py` таким образом Вы сделаете из `f2` модуль, должно сработать

Comment: ничего не изменилось

Comment: А если обратиться к функции так - `f1.foo()` вместо `foo()`

Comment: так импорт не проходит... как он увидит f1?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918539/can-anyone-explain-pythons-relative-imports

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175534/relative-imports-in-python

Comment: я видел все эти ссылки... в последней, там создается на уровень выше main.py где импортируются модуль которые в папках... у меня нет возможности создать файл на уровень выше, тогда будет портить все структуру проекта...

Comment: В файле f1.py ф-ция: Хочу вызвать из f2.py ф-цию foo() вы что и откуда вызываете ? и потом может __init__ поставить в директорию где f2.py лежит ?

Comment: если всё таки из f1.py то туда **__init__**  киньте